# Change window size using Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I'm using a Java telnet socket to connect to a network element and get some info. The connection works, and I can read the output.
Now I want to optimize the process, eliminating the pagination of each command's output.

The connection is made with the following code:

```
Socket soc = new Socket(ip,23);
InputStream in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
Writer out = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), false);
//... 
out.write(command+"\n");
out.flush();
//...
String output = readUntilPrompt(in);
```

So, when I execute some command with a long output, the result appears to fit the default terminal size (80x25) and I can read something like:

```
output line 
output line
[...]
output line
output line
Press any key to continue (Q to quit)
```

Doing the same, using the default terminal of Linux, the pagination occurs, but if I resize the window, the pagination disappears and all the output is printed to the console.

What I want is programmatically do the same with the Java socket. To "tell" the equipment that my Java client have a size like 100x1000, for example. 
I already tried the [Apache's Commons Net way](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/WindowSizeOptionHandler.html), but it not works.

Searching for answers, some people say you can send SIGWINCH signal or write something like this, but I don't know exactly it works:

```
out.write("\\e[8;200;200t");
```

Is there some code to send to the server to make it works?

Comment: Are you saying that your terminal is generating "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)" I've never seen that.

Comment: @slim Exactly! For some reason, the telnet client made by the "raw" Java socket sets the pagination like any other GUI client.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The solution is to use the suboption to negotiate window size, and use `BufferedOutputStream` instead of `PrintWriter`, because it is focused on deal with characters, not bytes.

[image]